# Concerns on SSL config within Websphere Application Server

Tags: websphere

i'm kind of confused with the SSL setting within Websphere Application Server.
As you can see from the attached picture, the Default SSL setting has been done both in cell and node scope. Below are my qeustions:

> 1. is either inbound or outbound data through websphere transfered with SSL way according to the setting?
> 2. is the above SSL setting enabled by default? If not, then how to enable it?

in the regard of KeyStore or TrustStore configuration, i can see it refers to path like

> ${CONFIG_ROOT}/cells/localhostCell01/key.p12

However, i can not find this variable `CONFIG_ROOT` within Webspehre Variables through Admin Console. Does it mean that SSL is disabled by default so it's ok for this variable having no value?

Thanks in advance
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please see the WebSphere Security Redbook chapter 4 for details - http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246316.pdf CONFIG_ROOT is a substitution variable, so you should be fine - http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ws.ast.st.v6.doc/topics/tsubvarv6.html. You can test which certificates are enabled using openssl from the command line - http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/test-ssl-certificates-diagnosis-ssl-certificate/

Comment: yes, i know `CONFIG_ROOT` is a substitution variable. however, it should be found from this path. (In the Integrated Solutions Console, under Environment | WebSphere Variables). But i can't see it there.

Comment: Your best bet is to switch on ssl tracing - http://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21162961 - and check the server logs, also try the openssl client to see what cert is being used

Comment: Like Dims says, `$CONFIG_ROOT` is an internal variable. You won't see it listed in the admin console, but it's there. You can find its value in `setupCmdLine.sh`, which will be `$WAS_HOME/config`.